# Date format conversion in AIX server

Tags: date, datetime, unix, aix

I am using AIX server.

I have a variable containing date returned from database i.e.

```
$ echo $date_var
12-JAN-17
```

Now i want to convert this string into yyyymmdd format. 
I issued the following command

```
date -d  $date_var +%Y%m%d
```

But I am getting error:

> date : illegal operation --d

I think AIX server does not support this functionality. What can I do instead?

Comment: In case of Oracle do this beforehand: `export NLS_DATE_FORMAT=YYYYMMDD`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Lorinczy , but i can't change the NLS parameter as i need date in multiple formatsin different variable.the code i shared is just a part of one big script

Comment: Guess you cannot install gnu!dateutils either. If it is Oracle, you can still use it to convert: `echo "select to_char(to_date('12-JAN-17','DD-MON-YY'),'YYYYMMDD') from dual;" |  sqlplus -S scott/tiger | tail -n2 | head -n1`

Comment: Thanks @Lorinczy ..that is a very good approach to handle it..thanks much :)

Comment: Can you use GNU awk?

Answer (score 0):

Could not add comment hence posting it as answer.
Can you check -u switch. reference [link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/date.htm)